# I am trying to find the zero-crossings just before and just after a peak using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the location of a peak from a recorded EEG channel and am trying to find the integral (area) of that peak using Matlab.  However, I am having trouble finding the zero-crossings just before and after the point where the peak is located.

I know the commands for how to find the zero-crossings, but I can't seem to make it automatically return the locations where the peak begins and ends.  I will eventually have to do this for multiple peaks and do not want to find each crossing manually.

The images I am working with look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data? When you say "peak" I assume you mean a single point that is a local maximum, but then you say you want to integrate under the peak, which suggests you mean it is a signal spanning some time frame.

Comment: The command I used to find the peak only gives me back the location of the max point, so that is the only info I have to work with.  The peak does occur over a short period of time, though. @BrianLynch

Comment: Well, you might be best off by looking at the zero crossings and finding the two which sorround your single peak. Shouldn't be hard to do. But is it just the maximal peak that interests you? Maybe you should look at all the peaks (probably by looking at the first/second derivative of your signals). **Edit**: single peak example: if max peak is at `x0`, and zero crossings are in array `zerocrosses`, then `ind1=find(zerocrosses<x0,1,'last')`, `ind2=find(zerocrosses>x0,1,'first')`, then your two zeroes are `zerocrosses(ind1)` and `zerocrosses(ind2)`.

Comment: @StephMoy have you perhaps had an opportunity to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you have all the zero crossings in the array `zerocrosses`, since you wrote

> I know the commands for how to find the zero-crossings

I'll also assume that you have the max peak position in `x0`, probably from

```
[~,imax]=max(EEGsignal);
x0=x(imax); %if your data pairs are EEGsignal vs x
```

OK, for completeness, here's a way to get the zero crossings:

```
inds=find(diff(sign(EEGsignal))); %find indices of sign change
zerocrosses=(x(inds+1)+x(inds))/2; %in between grid points
```

These `zerocrosses` will fall between `x` grid points for maximal precision. However, if for some reason you want to stick to your input `x` values then choosing `x(inds)` should suffice if your `x` is sufficiently dense (and this seems to be the case).

Then you can find those two zeros in your array which sorround `x0` by

```
ind1=find(zerocrosses<x0,1,'last');
ind2=find(zerocrosses>x0,1,'first');

first_cross=zerocrosses(ind1);
second_cross=zerocrosses(ind2);
```

The indices `ind1`,`ind2` will tell you the special indices of `zerocrosses` that you are looking for.

**Note**: in general you have to be a bit careful: it can happen that your peak is before the first zero, or after the last one. For this case you should check whether `isempty(first_cross)` or `isempty(second_cross)`. I didn't include this in my answer, because in this case your "peak" is ill-defined, and you shouldn't integrate it anyway (so it needs to be treated in a non-trivial way).